# extJS - Can not get data to render in GridPanel

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs

The below code uses `Ext.data.Store` to retrieve a JSON with table metadata (for the column headings) and the table's data. The backend PHP script is working correctly and the `Ext.data.Store` contains valid records for the data - I just can't get them to go "into" the Grid itself.

The API Documentation makes it seem as if I just define a `store` property for `Ext.grid.GridPanel` and it will handle the rest.

*Note: The code below is a separate from the rest of the application. We have pulled this portion out to see if we can just get a grid working, without the influence of the rest of the application.*

```
Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'js/ext/resources/images/default/s.gif';
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var columns = [];
    var fields = [];


    var tabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        activeTab: 0,
        height: 700
    });

    var queryHeaders = Ext.data.Record.create([
        {name: 'id'},
        {name: 'table'},
        {name: 'field'},
        {name: 'title'}
    ]);

    var applicationStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        autoLoad: true,
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({root: 'fields'}, queryHeaders),
        url: 'http://localhost/aargh/index.php/applications/hardware',
        listeners: {
            'load': function() {
                console.info(applicationStore);
                applicationStore.each(function(r) {
                    this_column = [];
                    this_column['header'] = r.data['title'];
                    this_column['dataIndex'] = r.data['id'];
                    columns.push(this_column);
                    this_column = []
                    this_column['name'] = r.data['id'];
                    fields.push(this_column);
                });

                console.info(fields);
                var queryFields = Ext.data.Record.create([fields]);

                var queryStore = new Ext.data.Store({
                    autoLoad: true,
                    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({root: 'fields'}, queryFields),
                    url: 'http://localhost/aargh/index.php/query/execute/applications/hardware',
                    listeners: {
                        'load': function() {
                            console.info(queryStore);
                            tabPanel.add(new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                                title: 'Hardware',
                                store: queryStore,
                                columns: columns,
                                autoHeight: true,
                                frame: true
                            }));
                            tabPanel.doLayout();
                        }
                    }
                }); 
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

As I review the `applicationStore` and `queryStore` objects in Firebug I can see the expected data results perfectly in `applicationStore.data.items.#.json` and `queryStore.data.items.#.json` (of course, replacing # with the record number).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow - this has been giving us trouble for three days. Turns out I was making an array within an array at `var queryFields = Ext.data.Record.create([fields]);`

Changing that to: `var queryFields = Ext.data.Record.create(fields);` fixed the issue.

Comment: Heh. So as soon as you posted you figured it out?

Comment: Shortly thereafter - been driving me crazy. Posted this and was cross-posting to extJS forums when I finally figured it out.